# ValueError: Tensor's shape (1, 1, 128, 18) is not compatible with supplied shape (1, 1, 128, 36) in Object Detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am trying to build an object detection model, using the object detection api, but while trying to predict the classes I am getting this error upon running the detect_fn(input_tensor) function, I have changed the number of classes from 90 to 5 and my batch size was 4, I closely followed this https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/object_detection_camera.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-object-detection-camera-py to setup my model. But I am getting this error **ValueError: Tensor's shape (1, 1, 128, 18) is not compatible with supplied shape (1, 1, 128, 36)**, could someone help me with this?

Comment: could you paste the code that you are using so that we can debug, or better upload a colab notebook.

Comment: Can you try to follow the steps that has mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9133#issuecomment-746064865) may resolve your issue. Thanks!